# Problem with pkg and crypto.generateKeyPairSync - "undefined is not a function"

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I have a problem with the executable generated with pkg using generating RSA keys (crypto.generateKeyPairSync).

I am working on Windows 10 machine with:

```
node -v: v12.16.3
npm -v: 6.14.4
pkg -v: 4.4.8
```

The code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

try {
    let { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
        modulusLength: 4096,
        publicKeyEncoding: {
            type: 'spki',
            format: 'pem'
        },
        privateKeyEncoding: {
            type: 'pkcs8',
            format: 'pem',
            cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
            passphrase: 'passphrase'
        }
    });

    console.log(publicKey)
    console.log(privateKey)

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

The pkg command:

```
pkg -t node8-win-x64 . --output ./builds/crypto-test.exe
```

The result (error):

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\snapshot\crypto-test\index.js:0:0)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1320:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:662:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:564:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1375:12)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:240:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:661:3
```

When I am using the same code without pkg - everything seems to work pefectly:

```
node .\index.js
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Can you guys help me with this issue? I spent hours trying to figure out how to fix this, but with no luck...

Thanks and greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using *node8-win-x64* in your package. But looks like your development machine is having v12 where it works. 
Use v12 in your package.

Comment: How can I miss that... now it is working like a charm :)
Thank you!